# Two queries optimize

Tags: mysql

I got two queries:

```
SELECT `type`, COUNT(`id`) AS 'type' FROM `items` WHERE `post` = `id` GROUP BY `type`;
SELECT `type`, COUNT(`post`!=`id`) AS 'posts' FROM `items` GROUP BY `type`;
```

Is there any way to make it in one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this

```
SELECT  `type`, 
        COUNT(`post`=`id`), 
        COUNT(`post`!=`id`) AS 'posts' 
FROM    `items` 
GROUP BY    `type`;
```

Comment: Query is OK, but this: `COUNT(`post`=`id`),` returns exactly the same rows values as `COUNT(`post`!=`id`) AS 'posts' ` it shouldnt be like that, since `COUNT(`post`=`id`),` this should return `5` in first row, but it returns `20` , same as for this: `COUNT(`post`!=`id`) AS 'posts'`.

Comment: You should use `SUM()` there instead of `COUNT()`.

Comment: YEs, that makes more sense, probably in both cases?